# Spring WebSocket: How to make a simple application with users that chat in rooms?

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

Fistly, I'm planning on using only the following dependency for Spring that is related to websockets:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and using @stomp/stompjs for React. I realized that a lot of examples dont go much beyond a chat that subscribe to like 1 or 2 endpoints. I also realized that a lot of examples and samples available use SockJs but I'm not going to need support for older browsers. Do you think these lib and dependecies choices are the right move in terms of variety of samples, good documentation etc?

Secondly, more related to the question: considering the Springboot application is mapped with classes User, ChatInvite and Chat, how can I code my @Controllers on Spring and the websocket operations on the front-end (subscribe, send etc) so that if I invite some user, this invited user have a popup on its screen with the options to accept or deny the chat.

Let's say the invite is accepted: I'm able to use a websocket endpoint to create the Chat_Invite register at the database with an id generated by sequence, chanllenger_id and challenged_id. Then I just return the id from the register just inserted.

But how can I return the information for *both* users that the invite was accepted and then create a @MessageMapping method for the Chat itself with a dynamic path?

I just want some example or some explanation about the process. Thanks.